# Does anyone know of any essays on Adam's Thesis and Deontic Conditionals?

Tags: logic, probability

I'm curious if anyone knows of any essays which concerns how deontic conditionals fit with Adam's Thesis.  (Adam's Thesis is the idea that the probability of an indicative conditional A > C is equal to the conditional probability of C given A).

Comment: Well, it's touched upon here. I've got some other stuff somehwere but it'll have to wait [Modus ponens](http://www.deon2014.ugent.be/file/2)

Comment: The basic mathematical subject would be Bayesian statistics, if that helps.  I doubt mathematicians have given much consideration to the deontic mode, but the way they consider the alethic mode with special statistics like 'possiblity theory' might connect up somewhere in the literature.

Comment: Araucaria -- are you sure Adams' thesis in the deontic context is discussed in that paper?  I didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, George, I was sure it was in there somewhere:( It might be another discussion of the mineshaft problem - but haven't been able to track it down ... Will have a proper route round when I get the chance ...

Comment: Sorry, George, I was sure it was in there somewhere:( It might be another discussion of the mineshaft problem - but haven't been able to track it down ... Will have a proper rummage for it when I get the chance ...